# 'CountVectorizer' object has no attribute 'toarray'

Tags: python, countvectorizer

I'm trying to vectorize some tweets so I can put it in a list and use it in a classficator.But it has a problem turn into DataFrame.[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `toarray()` method on `CountVectorizer`, you should use it on output of `fit_transform()` function to get features. This way -

```py
cvr = CountVectorizer(...)
X = cvr.fit_transform(...)

promo_value = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), ...)
```